# OpenCV Android native code build issue

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

I am learning how to write C++ code using OpenCV and I want to run it in Android. I use Android Studio.

I have created a new simple project with C++ support and then I added my test code to the C++ file. My own files compile and link, it seems.

Now something else that I don't think is related to my project is causing many errors. It seems to be something inside NDK. Could it be a bug in the latest version, and if so, what can I do about it?

```
  C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: C:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiCopyConstBorder_8u_C4IR_L_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
  C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: C:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiConvert_32s16u_C1RSfs_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
  C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: C:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiNormRel_L1_32f_C1R_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
  C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: C:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiFilterBilateralBorderInit_L_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
  C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: C:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiScaleC_32f8u_C1R_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
```

Comment: Attach the make file you are using to build C++ sources.

Comment: I reverted to NDK14 instead of using default latest NDK16 and the errors are gone!

Comment: @ScottJohansen I have the same problem since I updated AndroidStudio. How did you revert?

Comment: There seems to be an attempt to fix it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10288

Comment: The way I reverted was to simply download an older NDK from here and manually replace it.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Comment: Can you format your  findings to an answer? It may help somebody in future.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downgrading to NDK14 from NDK16 you can still do with NDK16 by adding following to the `CMakeLists.txt` before `add_library()` :

`set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a")`

Copied from [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10229) discussion on a github issue

Answer (score 1):

I reverted to NDK 14.1.3816874 instead of using the currently latest NDK 16.1.4479499, and the errors have disappeared.

The older NDK you can find here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: This could be because the defaults in NDK r16 have changed. To keep compatibility with prebuilt OpenCV libraries, you need to explicitly choose gnustl and gcc.